# How can I create a segmented foreach() function in PHP?

Tags: php, templates

Essentially I'm trying to create something that allows me to do this:

```
<?php
function herp(){foreach($users as $user):}
function derp(){endforeach;}
?>


<html><body>
<?php herp();?>

<?php $user->name();?>,<?php $user->name();?>,<?php $user->name();?>

<?php derp();?>
</body></html>   



--------- output ---------

John Doe, 1900, Buttery Yellow
Jane Doe, 1900, Platypus Brown
```

I do not want to create or rely on a template engine. I simply want to make it so the person who is creating the page templates can have loops available for him.

Comment: `make` is definitely not a proper tag here!

Comment: Checkout [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) - https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php

Comment: You can't split up a `foreach` like that, the `endforeach` is expected to be in the same scope.

Comment: is there a way to do this so it is within the same scope?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible and actually very popular. You need to use a [templating engine](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/).

What it does is basically allow you to separate the programming from the designing. In this case PHP from HTML. If you want to go with a simple one i recommend [Rain](http://www.raintpl.com/). Examples from site:

```
//PHP
include "inc/rain.tpl.class.php"; //include Rain TPL
raintpl::$tpl_dir = "tpl/"; // template directory
raintpl::$cache_dir = "tmp/"; // cache directory

<!--HTML-->
My age is {$age}  // 30

 and also use = for assign a value to a variable

{$year=30}
My age is {$age+$year}  // 60

You can use functions with variables

My name is {$name|substr:0,3}  // Rai
```

Comment: I just love how people layer templating engines on top of PHP, which is a templating in and of itself to begin with. Yo dawg...

Comment: @MarcB i do agree on that, but you cannot deny they are useful hommie.

Comment: I'm not looking to use an already established template engine. What I simply want to know is how would one go about segmenting a loop so that the beginning of the loop is called by a var or function and the end of the loop is called the same way.